# Query para retornar texto do meio de um campo

Tags: sql, query, regex, mysql

Tenho uma consulta que me retorna alguns nomes de turmas/**disciplinas**, porém eu queria que me trouxesse apenas os nomes das *disciplinas*. Abaixo segue o resultado da query com o padrão [turma]**[nome_da_disciplina]**[filial]:

ADM N1A **COMUNICAÇÃO OFICIAL**  (MES)

ADM N1A **FILOSOFIA LÓGICA E ÉTICA**  (MES)

ADM D1A **COMUNICAÇÃO OFICIAL**  (AB)

ADM D1A **FILOSOFIA LÓGICA E ÉTICA**  (AB)

ADM N1A **FILOSOFIA LÓGICA E ÉTICA**  (AB)

PGER N1A **LEGISLAÇÃO SOCIAL E TRABALHISTA**  (MES)

CCONT N1A **TEORIA DA CONTABILIDADE**  (MES)

FIN N1A **COMUNICAÇÃO OFICIAL**  (MES)

---

Percebi o seguinte padrão: o nome da disciplina começa logo depois do 2º espaço e termina logo antes do último espaço (antes do espaço que precede o "abre parênteses").

Para a string:
[FIN N1A **COMUNICAÇÃO OFICIAL**  (MES)]

Eu desejo retornar apenas:
[**COMUNICAÇÃO OFICIAL**]

Não conheço muito do mysql, então vou receber qualquer ajuda de coração.

*P.S. PRECISO PASSAR ESSE FILTRO DIRETAMENTE NA CONSULTA (QUERY MYSQL)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar `substring_index` e `replace` eliminando os dois primeiros trechos e o último. A query abaixo irá retornar uma coluna chamada `resultado` com a string tratada:

```
select *,
trim(
   replace(
      replace(
         substring_index(
            substring(texto, instr(texto, " ")+1), " ", 10
         ),
         substring_index(
            substring(texto, instr(texto, " ")+1), " ", 1
         ), ''
      ),
      substring_index(
         substring(texto, instr(texto, " ")+1), " ", -1
      ), ''
   )
) as resultado
from tabela
```

Veja exemplo no **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/659911/8)**.

Comment: Desculpe por não especificar na pergunta, mas é que preciso passar esse filtro diretamente na consulta (query mysql). Vou alterar a descrição da pergunta agora mesmo.

Comment: Não, não tem. Não coloquei tag jquery nessa pergunta, coloquei query. Mas agradeço, @dvd

Comment: Eu já havia testado aki diversas formas e tinha consegui agora à pouco com a consulta abaixo:

**select substr(curso, length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(curso, ' ',2))+2, INSTR(curso,'  (')-length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(curso, ' ',2))-2) from tabela;**

Mas obrigado, @dvd. Sua query rodou exatamente como eu precisava.